# Explicit expression for integral of $(1-a~x^{-1/2}-b~x)^{-3/2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

I wonder if there exists an explicit solution to the integral $$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{d{u}}{\sqrt{(1-a/\sqrt{u}-b~u)^{3}}}\tag{1}$$ Any help or advice is welcome.

**Appendix**

The full expression with integral $(1)$ reads
\begin{equation}
f(x)=(1-a/\sqrt{x}-b~x)^{1/2}\bigg\{1+p_1/4~(1-a-b)^{1/2}\int_{1}^{x}(1-a/\sqrt{u}-b~u)^{-3/2}d{u}\bigg\}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $x\in [1,\infty)$, $p_1\ge 0, $ $a\in[0,1]$ and $b\le 1-a$. The expression $(2)$ defines a real-valued non-negative function $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it.

Comment: I doubt. there is an explicit solution. but if wolfram alpha  for example is a better place to ask

Comment: @trula Wolfram alpha does not show one, at least the free version.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks for the hint. I will try it.

Comment: @user10354138 I am afraid it does not help.

Comment: @JanG Another complication here is the expression under the square root can be negative for some choices of positive $a,b$. Are you wanting to consider those cases too?

Comment: Maple evaluates this integral  in terms of Ellliptic integrals E and F.  Maple's answer is many pages long.

Comment: @DavidH Negative $b$ would help me, too. It stands for Einstein's cosmological constant $\Lambda$ ($b=\Lambda/3$) which in that case would be negative.

Comment: @GEdgar That is a great news. I need that integral to write down explicitly Schwarzschild's cosmological solution to Einstein field equations with non-zero cosmological constant. It there any possibility to get that integral without buying Maple?

Comment: @JanG If the integral represents a physical quantity, then presumably it’s intended to be real-valued, so more care will be needed restricting the values of $a$ and $b$ before we even start evaluating the integral. You should also specify the range of $x$ if you can.

Comment: The "full expression" $(2)$ really includes $a\sqrt{u}$ and not $a/\sqrt{u}$ ?  In that case, $$\int \! \left( 1-a\sqrt {x}-bx \right) ^{-3/2}\,{\rm d}x=2\,
{\frac {1}{b\sqrt {1-a\sqrt {x}-bx}}}-2\,{\frac {a \left( -2\,b\sqrt {
x}-a \right) }{b \left( -{a}^{2}-4\,b \right) \sqrt {1-a\sqrt {x}-bx}}}$$

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry it was typing error, thanks.

Comment: @DavidH Thanks for your comment. I have completed my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It there any possibility to get that integral without buying Maple?**
I do not know why such a thing would be useful.

Here is a shorter one, with an answer only one page long.

We are interested in the indefinte integral
$$
\int \frac{d{x}}{\sqrt{(1-a/\sqrt{x}-bx)^{3}}}
\tag1$$
substitute $u=\sqrt{x}$ to get
$$
2i\int\frac{u^{5/2}\,du}{(bu^3-u+a)^{3/2}}
\tag2$$
Factor the cubic polynomial (over the complex numbers); then it suffices to evaluate
$$
\int\frac{u^{5/2}}{\big((u-a1)(u-a2)(u-a3)\big)^{3/2}}
\tag3$$
According to Maple, this is
`-2/u^(1/2)*(2*u^2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3* (u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/ (-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^2*a2^3*a3-u^2*a1^2*a3^4+u^2*a1^3*a3^3+u^2*a2^3*a3^3+6*u*((- a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/ 2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^2 *a2^2*a3^3-4*u*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u- a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(- a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1*a2^3*a3^3+2*u^2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u -a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2), (a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2^2*a3-2*u^2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2 )*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u /a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2*a3^2-4*u*((-a3+a1)*u /a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)* EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^2*a2 ^2*a3^3+4*u*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1) /a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+ a1))^(1/2))*a1*a2^3*a3^3+u^2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3)) ^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*( -a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2^2*a3+u^2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*( u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u- a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2*a3^2-u^2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u- a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF((( -a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^2*a2^3*a3-3*u^2* ((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^ (1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))* a1^2*a2^2*a3^2+2*u^2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*( a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/ a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1*a2^3*a3^2-2*u*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2 /(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/ 2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2^2*a3^2-2*u*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^( 1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1 )*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2*a3^3-4*u*((-a3+a1 )*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)* EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2 ^2*a3^2+4*u*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1) /a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+ a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2*a3^3-4*u*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3)) ^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*( -a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^2*a2^3*a3^2+2*u^2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*( a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1 /(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^2*a2^2*a3^2-2*u^2*((-a3+a1)* u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)* EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1*a2^3 *a3^2+4*u*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/ a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1 ))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2^3*a3+2*u*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^( 1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(- a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^2*a2^3*a3^2+((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u- a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3 ))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2^2*a3^3+((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3)) ^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+ a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2*a3^4-((-a3+a1)* u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)* EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^2*a2 ^3*a3^3-3*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/ a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1 ))^(1/2))*a1^2*a2^2*a3^4+2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^( 1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticF(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(- a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1*a2^3*a3^4-2*u^2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3* (u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u -a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2^3-2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3)) ^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+ a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2^3*a3^2+2*((-a3+ a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)* EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2 ^2*a3^3-2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/ a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1 ))^(1/2))*a1^3*a2*a3^4+2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/ 2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+ a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^2*a2^3*a3^3+2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2 )/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3)) ^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1^2*a2^2*a3^4-2*((-a3+a1)*u/a1/(u-a3)) ^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a2)/a2/(u-a3))^(1/2)*(a3*(u-a1)/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2)*EllipticE(((-a3+ a1)*u/a1/(u-a3))^(1/2),(a1*(-a3+a2)/a2/(-a3+a1))^(1/2))*a1*a2^3*a3^4-2*u^2*a1^2 *a2^2*a3^2+2*u^2*a1*a2^2*a3^3+3*u*a1^3*a2^2*a3^2+2*u^2*a1^2*a2*a3^3+3*u*a1^2*a2 ^3*a3^2-2*u^2*a1^3*a2*a3^2-2*u^2*a1*a2^3*a3^2-2*u*a1^3*a2^3*a3-u*a1^3*a2*a3^3-u *a1*a2^3*a3^3-4*u*a1^2*a2^2*a3^3+u*a1^2*a2*a3^4+u^2*a1^3*a2^2*a3+u^2*a1^2*a2^3* a3+u*a1*a2^2*a3^4-u^2*a2^2*a3^4)/((u-a1)*(u-a2)*(u-a3))^(1/2)/(-a3+a1)^2/(-a3+ a2)^2/a3/(-a2+a1)^2`

Writing the three roots `a1,a2,a3` in terms of radicals using Cardano's formula produces a multi-page answer as I mentioned in a comment.

Comment: GEdgar Thanks a lot!

Comment: Of course. It’s so obvious in hindsight….